# Ubuntu 14.04 Thinkpad w520 Three monitors only after turn on and connect to dock

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, thinkpad

I have been trying to set up a three-monitor configuration on my laptop.

I have a Thinkpad w520 with a Lenovo Thinkpad dock station also, Nvidia card with Optimus support and nvidia-331 drivers installed, also Intel graphics card. I had the same configuration a while ago but it broke after an upgrade. I decided to reinstall version 14.04.0 and update bit by bit.

Now (without updating much), I can only get the three monitors working when turning on the laptop and afterwards connecting it to the docking station.

When restarting the laptop in the docking station, only two external monitors can be used and the built-in monitor of the laptop goes black: I can see the mouse on it but nothing more.

*Any idea on what should I tweak for fixing this?*

Answer (score 0):

I had this working on a Dell E6520 with the eport+ docking station on Ubuntu 14.04.1. The drivers that I had working correctly were the following packages. Once I got them working I then pinned them through synaptic.

```
libcuda1-331_331.38-0ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb
nvidia-331_331.38-0ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb
nvidia-331-uvm_331.38-0ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb
nvidia-libopencl1-331_331.38-0ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb
nvidia-opencl-icd-331_331.38-0ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb
```

following that I created the following in my .xprofile

```
export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource Intel NVIDIA-0
xrandr --output DP-0 --left-of LVDS1
xrandr --output DP-1 --right-of LVDS1
```

obviously you will need to modify for your specific outputs from xrandr.
The export is because I like my scroll bars.
The newer versions of the drivers will give me live screens at login on either of the external monitors, but once I log in the laptop display will go loose the background and only show the mouse pointer but nothing else. the Displays settings from the unity dash shows all of the monitors correctly.
I've since updated to 14.04.2 and the 331.38 drivers are not compatible with the newer xorg-core packages.

I just wanted to add that I had a meeting earlier today and booted the laptop out of the dock and then docked it after the meeting without a reboot and all three monitors are working. I'm using the xorg-edgers PPA currently on 346.47-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1. My .xprofile only contains my scrollbar export.

Comment: From last paragraph I can conclude we both have same results, right? Have you manage to get the 3 monitors when rebooting with laptop in dock station?

Comment: No unfortunately I haven't. I've just been booting with it out of the dock and then inserting it. It's an extra step but until I can figure out what the issue is it's better than having a black monitor.

Comment: Yes. I'm doing the same currently. I came up with another scenario: removing laptop from docking station while it is on. Then can not get any external monitors back when docking only built in.

Comment: Just an FYI. I see the issues with 16.04 as well. The boot out of dock and insert seems to still the easiest way of making all three work.